# Multiple Left Outer Join with lambda expressions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, lambda

I have an SQL Query to do with Lambda Expressions like this, generally with more joins than in this example.

```
select Table2.a,
          Table2.b,
          Table2.c,
          Table2.d
   from Table1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
     ON Table2.a = Table1.a and
        Table2.b = Table1.b and
        Table2.c = Table1.c 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3
     ON Table3.b = Table1.b AND
        Table3.c = Table1.c AND
        Table3.d = Table1.d 
   where ( Table1.a = ValueA )
   order by Table3.f
```

I'm doing this with Join() Lambda Expression, but i see in SQL Server profiler that this generate an INNER JOIN and i need a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

This is how i'm doing it with Join()

```
var RS = DBContext.Table1.Join(DBContext.Table2,
  Table1 => new {Table1.a, Table1.b, Table1.c},
  Table2 => new {Table1.a, Table1.b, Table1.c},
  (Table1, Table2) => new {Table1})
.Join(DBContext.Table3,
  LastJoin => new {LastJoin.Table1.b, LastJoin.Table1.c, LastJoin.Table1.d},
  Table3 => new {Table3.b, Table3.c, Table3.d},
  (LastJoin,Table3) => new {LastJoin.Table1, Table3})
.Where (LastTable => LastTable.Table1.a == ValueA)
.OrderBy(LastTable => LastTable.Table3.f)
.Select (LastTable => new {LastTable.Table1, LastTable.Table3});
```

I have been reading that it can be done with DefaultIfEmpty() or GroupJoin() but i haven't find any complex example with more than one LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Can you show which navigation properties you've got? This is so much easier when you can use syntax like `orderby table1.Table3.f`.

Comment: Hello, my lambda expression dos not indicate it because i want all the fields of the entities that is the reason of the select at the end of the lambda expression.

Comment: Sinceyou know how to write teh query with left joins, why not directly call it or put it in a stored proc and call it?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try using linq query, it is also much easier to write and understand both as compared to lambda expressions. I have on such implementation like:

```
var products = 
        from p in this.Products
        from cat in this.ProductCategoryProducts
        .Where(c => c.ProductID == p.ProductID).DefaultIfEmpty()

        from pc in this.ProductCategories 
        .Where(pc => ac.ProductCategoryID == cat.ProductCategoryID).DefaultIfEmpty()

        where p.ProductID == productID
        select new
        {
            ProductID = p.ProductID,
            Heading = p.Heading,                
            Category = pc.ProductCategory
        };
    return products ;
```